# c++ Reading big text file to string (bigger than string::max_size)

Tags: c++, string, text-files

I have a **huge text file (~5GB)** which is the **database** for my program. During run this database is **read completely many times** with string functions like string::find(), string::at(), string::substr()...

The problem is that this text file cannot be loaded in one string, because **string::max_size** is definitely too small.

How would you implement this? I had the idea of loading a part to string->reading->closing->loading another part to same string->reading->closing->...
Is there a better/more efficient way?

Comment: I think that the fact you want to do this indicates a poor/lazy design (sorry).  You could at least create simple functions that will search the file itself rather than loading the whole thing into memory and working with that.  Keep in mind that if sufficient memory is available and you are doing this fairly often, most modern OS's will keep it in RAM anyway, so there should not be a huge bottleneck.

Comment: Presumably adding "64 bit processor and 8GB of RAM" to the program's hardware requirements isn't an option? In terms of development work, that's by far the most efficient solution. Otherwise, using a real database might be a good idea.

Comment: Which OS/compiler? gcc/linux 64-bit has about a `2^62` `max_size`.

Comment: To add to Mike's comment, I would advise specialized text search engines such as Lucene. If your input is text and your queries are text-oriented, using a generic database is likely a mismatch.

Comment: @goldilocks you are right, I was indeed very lazy, because I was familiar with the string:: functions I wanted to use them. Are there equivalent functions with **ifstream** - or which function for "find" etc would you suggest? I could try it and see if it is acceptable performance wise.

MSalters, thanks for mentioning **Lucene** - I will have a closer look and see if I can use it.

Comment: That depends a lot on how the file is laid out (something you might want to give some thought to).  Eg, if you are looking for something on one line, you can read through one line at a time and search it as a string. However, that probably won't work for everything. If the file has a definite structure, you can also make use of ifstream::seekg(), which would be a bonus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would you implement this?

With a real database, for instance SQLite.  The performance improvement from having indexes is more than going to make up for your time learning another API.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a database, I'm assuming it'd have many records. That to me implies best idea would be to implement a data class for each records and populate a list/vector/etc depending upon how you plan to use it. I'd also look into persistent cache as the file is big.

And within in your container class of all records, you could implement search etc functions as you see fit. But as suggested for a db of this size, you're probably best of using a database.